# Is it possible to attach discussion board to a node?

Tags: 7, comments, nodes

I have a content type called "Movies". I would like to create discussion threads  under it similar to discussion threads in imdb.com under a movie. I have tried the advanced forum module and also brain forum module. They don't seem to do that I have in my mind.

Is there a module which does this job? I think I will have to use advanced forum module and use a content type for forum discussion and then use entity reference and entity reference prepopulate to link it to the other content type. Is there a better and cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the core comment module.

(If you want to order the newest comments at the top then see [Comment goodness](https://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness))

Comment: I am not sure how we can create threads then? Using comments would have one topic discussion around the node than multiple topics and discussions around the node.

Comment: Comments support threading